# Convert a mixed mode application project (.exe) to a mixed mode dynamic library (.dll)

Tags: visual-studio, dll, c++-cli, mixed-mode

I have a project containing both native and managed C++ code.
Its runtime support is set to `/clr`.
Its configuration type used to be set to `Application`, such that it compiled to an `.exe`. This worked all fine.
But now I want to use this project as a library (.dll) for another project.
So I change the configuration type to dynamic library and rename the `main()` function to something else.
Then rebuilding the project gives the following two errors.

```
Error   2   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   C:\Projects\MyProject\Source\Debug\MyProject.dll    MyProject
Error   1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _main C:\Projects\MyProject\Source\CppSource\LINK     MyProject
```

The corresponding output is as follows.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: MyProject, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Main.cpp
1>LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _main
1>C:\Projects\MyProject\Source\Debug\MyProject.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Am I forgetting something here?

Comment: See some help here [C++/CLI and mixed mode programming](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/abhinaba/archive/2012/11/14/c-cli-and-mixed-mode-programming.aspx)

Comment: Are you referring to a specific section? It seems like a general guide to mixed mode. This question is specific to creating a dll from an exe project.

Comment: Hard to imagine what could have gone wrong, this works without hassle when I try it.  Be sure to change the configuration type for *all* configurations.  And check the Linker > Advanced > Entry Point setting, it should be blank.

Comment: The entry point setting seemed to have done the trick. Thanks a lot for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

As Hans Passant suggested, the entry point setting must be blank.

*This answer mainly exists to be able to mark this post as solved.*

Comment: Hmm, this is not a very useful answer.  At least explain how this setting ended up having the wrong value so other programmers can avoid falling into the same trap.

Comment: I'm not sure myself. The value was set to `main`, which used to be the entry point indeed. Maybe this value was set explicitly  in the process of porting native code to managed code.